# JavaScript scrollTop not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, scrolltop

I am trying to develop an application, but I ran into a problem. You know real applications like Apple's Shortcuts or Cydia, when you scroll they all have an effect with the titles at the top, I have two examples here: https://streamable.com/j5yu5

I am trying to do the same, it does work on the computers, but not on my mobile phone (iPhone 7+, running iOS 12.1.1, Jailbroken, tried fullscreen safari, webclip)

here is my code right now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Adam Izgin</title>
 <script src="http://koda.nu/arkivet/94004581"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <style>

  * {
   font-family: Chalkboard SE;
  }

  html, body {
   background: #fff;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

  body {
   height: 150vh;
  }
  
  #header {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 50px;
   background: #fff;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  }

  #title {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: 900;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
  }

  .title {
   margin: 40px 20px;
   font-weight: 900;
   font-size: 30px;
   opacity: 1;
  }

  #top {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  }

 </style>
 <script>
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
   get('html').end(function() {
    if (html.scrollTop > 30) {
     alert('Hello, World!');
    };
   });
  });

 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="top"></div>

 <div id="header">
  <h1 id="title">text</h1>
 </div>

   <h1 class="title" id="title1">text</h1>
 
</body>
</html>
```

open the snippet in fullscreen, and inspect as a mobile and drag with the mouse instead of scrolling. That works on my computer, but not on my phone. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

ps: the **get**-function is the same as the jQuery's **$**, and the **end**-function is the same as on**touchend**

Answer (score 7):

After a **lot** of research I came up with a solution.
**document.documentElement.scrollTop** does not work in mobile browsers, so we have to use **window.pageYOffset** instead.

Comment: Thanks for  the window.pageYOffset solution! What I find is document.documentElement.scrollTop does work on Chrome(83.0.4103.106) on my Android(8.0.0) phone, while it doesn't work on Chrome(83.0.4103.88) and Safari(12.1) on my iPad(iOS 12.4.7)

Comment: pageYOffset seems to be deprecated, use the alias scrollY instead, unless you need old browser support. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/pageyoffset)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`
It works perfectly fine on both ios and other platforms

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work in my tests right now.

Answer (score 0):

above methods didnt work for me on mobile browsers:
then I used the below code and worked properly:

first, need to define an id for your page container as `body-container` then:

```
    document.getElementById('body-container').scrollTo(0, 0)
```

in angular I put this code in `router.events` to trigger it after any routing:

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
   document.getElementById('body-container').scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Bard:
"Viewport Resizing: On most mobile browsers, the viewport (visible area) resizes to accommodate the keyboard, pushing content upward and potentially making scrollTo(0, 0) ineffective."

On Android window.scrollTo( 0, 0 ) doesn't work when the virtual keyboard is open. It does work on Safari though.

ref: https://g.co/bard/share/dd329f9a9b53