# scrollTop does not work on mobile devices

Tags: html, jquery

What this code fraction does is, move a div when the scroll reaches the footer, it works fine on desktop but it doesn't work on mobile.
Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function () { 
      if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == $(document).height()) {                $('.publicar-btn').stop(true).animate({ // Escondemos el div
              bottom: 150
          }, 250);
      } else { 
          $('.publicar-btn').stop(true).animate({ 
              bottom: 30
          }, 200);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You may not reach the "footer" on mobile devices, as the toolbar pops in ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript scrollTop not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088464/javascript-scrolltop-not-working-on-mobile)